# Pitivi won't render in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video-editor, codecs, gstreamer, pitivi

I've recently upgraded 11.10 to 12.04 and then reinstalled Pitivi and Gstreamer codecs ecxept the extra codecs and regardless of which container,vid codec or aud codec the rendering bar wouldn't move any help would be helpful, and if your wondering if it used to work in 11.10 it only work in the first few tries before it also stopped rendering.

P.S: I'm still a nooby.

Comment: Do the same videos play in other tools (particularly totem, the built-in video player)?  Also, which particular gstreamer codec packages did you install?  Do you have everything in `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Answer (score 4):

The version 0.15.1 installed via the repository has this problem, but do these steps will solve (by compiling 0.15.2):

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and enter these commands (after each line typed below press "Enter"):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep pitivi
wget -c http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pitivi/0.15/pitivi-0.15.2.tar.xz
tar Jxvf pitivi-0.15.2.tar.xz
cd pitivi-0.15.2/
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately :-(

Comment: OK, not only did it not work, but now i can't even edit the video even after a restart, whyyy :'(

Answer (score 3):

My problem with pitivi was that it did not show any progress in the render dialog and just kept raising the 'estimated time' to finish rendering.

After the guys on #pitivi asked me what container/codecs I used, I switched the video codec from "Dirac" to "Theora" and I could render my video. I had the Ogg container, Theora for video, and Vorbis for audio.

I'm not sure right now what version of pitivi comes with 12.04, but I did install 0.15.2 from the sources at the end. Maybe you did the same (installing 0.15.2) but didn't try some other video codec instead of Dirac?

Answer (score 1):

This bug was reported on **2011-12-10**

Bug 665902 - Render never completes because of a not-linked element

See : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665902

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread several years later trying to render a video in Ubuntu 16.04 using Pitivi 0.95

I found that I was unable to render to mp4 format, but was able to use other formats. avi worked best for me. I realize this is not an acceptable solution for everyone, but if you absolutely need mp4 perhaps you can find some other means to convert to mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flatpak](https://flatpak.org/). Thanks to running the app into a container, it's almost impossible you get an error to run the latest version. The latest version is much faster and more stable. There setup instruction is [here](http://developer.pitivi.org/Install_with_flatpak.html?gi-language=undefined).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you completely remove Pitivi and reinstall through the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pitivi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pitivi
```

That should remove Pitivi and reinstall it :) Now if that doesn't help, I suggest you try a new editor. Pitivi has been known to have it's issues, that's why it was removed as a default application in Ubuntu. My favoured video editor is Open shot, available in the Ubuntu Software Center. There are however users who remote stability issues. It is powerful, versatile and fun to use. Most importantly the developers are actively improving it:  http://www.openshotvideo.com/

There is also Kdenlive, often hailed as the best free video editor on Linux. http://www.kdenlive.org/

Comment: pitivi is still in Ubuntu main so it's still fully supported.  It's just no longer installed by default or included on the Live CD.  It hasn't been replaced by another video editor.

Comment: Yes it is still supported, but it still has a rough track history which played in the decision toto remove it. I'm not saying its bad, but maybe another editor might do better for you.

Comment: Ok i have installed both opeshot and Kdenlive, firstly openshot crashes before it can even fully load and kdenlive is complaining of not being compatible with most of the gstreamer codecs, so anyone else......please:(

Comment: http://iloveubuntu.net/kdenlive-092-released-bug-fixes-ppa-available

Comment: OK, Openshots now working, but now its also not compatible with most of my Gstreamer codecs, but at least i can edit and render my vids at 720 or 1080p on ogg, still prefer Pitivi though :(